# Dismiss notification message color selection

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, information-display

The new dismiss notification message color selection is bad on the eyes, don't you think? I have searched meta and did not find anything similar.

The message `click on this box to dismiss` is hard to look at and causes headache easily enough.

Here is an example from SO:

[image: From SO, the new dismiss]

---

as compared to programmers.SE:

[image: From programmers.SE, the new dismiss]

Edit: I noticed just now that the `Thanks, we'll take a look (Click on this box to dismiss)` notification when I flagged a post as Off-Topic is clearly better than the one I have highlighted here. I could not capture a screenshot quickly enough.

Wow, Thanks Jeff and Jin for quick resolution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug. I have put in a fix. It will be in the next build.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. This is my first time raising a bug in Meta. Can you please guide me how to appropriately tag the question?

Comment: @steeluser just tag it with "css" and "design." If the problem is with a specific SE site only, then raise the issue on that site's Meta.

Comment: Thanks jin I have retagged accordingly.